# Cannot do database-first model generation

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

This is how my project.json looks like.

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.1.2",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "type": "platform",
      "version": "1.1.1"
    },
    "NLog.Web.AspNetCore": "4.3.1"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet": " 1.1.0-preview4-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },
  "runtimes": {
    "win8-x64": {}
  },
  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "Views",
      "Areas/**/Views",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config",
    ]
  },
  "scripts": {
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

I am using VS2015 update 3.

[image]

I have .NET Core 1.1.1 installed

[image]

Here are contents of related folder.
[image]

Problem is that I am not able to reverse engineer the database. Below is what I am getting when I am running command against my ASP.NET Core project.

```
PM> Scaffold-DbContext "Server=MY-PC;Database=MyDatabase;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models 
Startup project 'src\MyProject' is an ASP.NET Core or .NET Core project for Visual Studio 2015. This version of the Entity Framework Core Package Manager Console Tools doesn't support these types of projects.
```

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Why are you using `1.1.0-preview4-final`? the full release version was [released over a month ago](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet/1.0.0) Also, lots and lots of packages are going to be dropping support for VS2015 and .NET core. If you want continued support of your libraries and the framework itself you will need to move to VS2017

Comment: Using 1.0.0 of Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet causes me following error "
Unable to resolve 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet (>= 1.1.0)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0'.". Visual Studio 2017 is not approved to be used in my company yet unfortunately.

Comment: What does this question have to do with reverse engineering anything?

Comment: I have reworded your title to use the proper terminology.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `Scaffold-DbContext` PM because this tool doesn't support VS 2015 project but you can use `dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold` instead
[Entity Framework Core Scaffold DbContext from Existing Database](http://dotnetthoughts.net/entity-framework-core-scaffold-dbcontext-from-existing-database/)

sample :

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Server=MY-PC;Database=MyDatabase;Trusted_Connection=True;" -o Models Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
```

Comment: interesting. My colleague actually is able to use scaffold-DbContext. She basically gave me this command that she is using on her system. She has an older version of .NET core though (1.1.0) and i am not sure if this is something that got changed in the latest version (1.1.1) that I installed.

Comment: it's propably a side effect of switching from project.json to msbuild in 1.1.1